# Django REST Framework: return 404 (not 400) on POST if related field does not exist?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-signals

I'm developing a REST API which takes POST requests from some really brain-dead software which can't PATCH or anything else. The POSTs are to update Model objects which already exist in the database.

Specifically, I'm POSTing data for objects with a related field (a SlugRelatedField, as the POSTer knows the 'name' attribute but NOT the 'pk').  However, I need to return a 404 if the POSTer sends data where the 'name' returns nothing on the SlugRelatedField (e.g. the related object does not exist).  I've been through this with a debugger but it seems that DRF uses some Django signals magic to do it The Way DRF Does It™, which is to return a 400 BAD REQUEST.  I don't know how to modify this - *only* when it's the above condition and not a true 400-worthy POST - into a 404.

By the way, `pre_save()` in my view is NOT executing during execution of the failing test.

Here's the serializer:

```
class CharacterizationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Work-in-progress for django-rest-framework use.  This handles (de)serialization
    of data into a Characterization object and vice versa.

    See: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization
    """
    creator = serializers.Field(source='owner.user.username')
    sample = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name',
                                          required=True,
                                          many=False,
                                          read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Characterization
        # leaving 'request' out because it's been decided to deprecate it. (...maybe?)
        fields = ('sample', 'date', 'creator', 'comments', 'star_volume', 'solvent_volume',
                  'solution_center', 'solution_var', 'solution_minimum', 'solution_min_stddev',
                  'solution_test_len',)
```

And here's the view where `pre_save` isn't being run in the given test (but does get run in some others):

```
class CharacterizationList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Characterization.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CharacterizationSerializer
    permission_classes = (AnonPostAllowed,)   # @todo XXX hack for braindead POSTer

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        # user isn't sent as part of the serialized representation,
        # but is instead a property of the incoming request.
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            obj.owner = get_dummy_proxyuser()   # this is done for CharacterizationList so unauthed users can POST. @todo XXX hack
        else:
            obj.owner = ProxyUser.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)

        # here, we're fed a string sample name, but we need to look up
        # the actual sample model.
        # @TODO: Are we failing properly if it doesn't exist?  Should
        # throw 404, not 400 or 5xx.
        # except, this code doesn't seem to be run directly when debugging.
        # a 400 is thrown; DRF must be bombing out before pre_save?
        obj.sample = Sample.objects.get(name=self.request.DATA['sample'])
```

And for good measure, here's the failing test:

```
def test_bad_post_single_missing_sample(self):
    url = reverse(self._POST_ONE_VIEW_NAME)

    my_sample_postdict = self.dummy_plqy_postdict.copy()
    my_sample_postdict["sample"] = "I_DONT_EXIST_LUL"
    response = self.rest_client.post(url, my_sample_postdict)
    self.assertTrue(response.status_code == 404,
                    "Expected 404 status code, got %d (%s). Content: %s" % (response.status_code, response.reason_phrase, response.content))
```

If I put a breakpoint in at the `self.rest_client.post()` call, the response already has a 400 in it at that point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `pre_save` why not override `post` in your API view:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...other stuff
    try:
        obj.sample = Sample.objects.get(name=self.request.DATA['sample'])
        ...or whatever other tests you want to do
    except:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    response = super(CharacterizationList, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return response
```

Make sure you import DRF's status:

```
from rest_framework import status
```

Also, note you will likely want to be more specific with the Exceptions you catch. Django's `get` method will return either `DoesNotExist` if nothing matches or `MultipleObjectsReturned` if more than one object matches. [The relevant documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get):

> Note that there is a difference between using get(), and using
>   filter() with a slice of [0]. If there are no results that match the
>   query, get() will raise a DoesNotExist exception. This exception is an
>   attribute of the model class that the query is being performed on - so
>   in the code above, if there is no Entry object with a primary key of
>   1, Django will raise Entry.DoesNotExist.
>
> Similarly, Django will complain if more than one item matches the
>   get() query. In this case, it will raise MultipleObjectsReturned,
>   which again is an attribute of the model class itself.

Comment: Thanks! Quick question - is get_object_or_404 inappropriate to use if overriding POST in this way? I'm still new to DRF and I'm a bit confused about when it expects Response objects or not.

Comment: Answered my own comment. I ended up omitting the try/except and using a dummy get_object_or_404 call in an overridden post() much as you specify, just to throw the 404 right away.  I then used @fixmycode's suggestion below, too, for good measure. I wish I could accept both answers. All my tests pass now, thanks much.

Comment: @GordonMorehouse There's nothing wrong with using `get_object_or_404` I just like using DRF's status options as it keeps all my response status code consistent and it [provides nearly all the HTTP codes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/status-codes). I'll +1 @fixmycode's answer for ya!

Comment: I'm having difficulties to find the module where `Response` appears. Any clues?

Comment: @dabad Try `from rest_framework.response import Response`

Answer (score 8):

You can use a Django Shortcut for that, getting the obj.sample:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
obj.sample = get_object_or_404(Sample, name=self.request.DATA['sample'])
```

Comment: Thanks - a friend suggested that to me, but it didn't work because pre_save() is not being run in this case. I may end up adding it in addition to other code to fix the problem though. Also, my original comment to this effect disappeared mysteriously.

Comment: Then you may want to address the issue of pre_save not running first, the most probable cause it's an exception in the parsing of the post data, maybe because of permissions. Try using AllowAny

Comment: I'll check into it - the view is set up so that aaaanybody in the world can POST, though, and response.content is complaining that the Sample with the given name doesn't exist - so if there's a permissions problem, it's not revealed yet. I'm just back to working with the code now - thanks for your hints.