# How do you return 404 when resource is not found in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-404

When a user inputs a url that is wrong, my Django app returns an HTML error. How can I get DRF to return a json formatted error?

Currently my urls is

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from snippets import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^snippets/$', views.snippet_list),
    url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.snippet_detail),
]
```

but if a user goes to 127.0.0.1:8000/snip They get the html formatted error rather than a json formatted error.

Comment: get_object_or_404

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Simply way to do it, you can use `raise Http404`, here is your `views.py`

```
from django.http import Http404

from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from yourapp.models import Snippet
from yourapp.serializer import SnippetSerializer


class SnippetDetailView(APIView):

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

You also can handle it with `Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)`, this answer is how to do with it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24420524/6396981

But previously, inside your `serializer.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from yourapp.models import Snippet


class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.CharField(
        source='user.pk',
        read_only=True
    )
    photo = serializers.ImageField(
        max_length=None,
        use_url=True
    )
    ....

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('user', 'title', 'photo', 'description')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Snippet.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

To test it, an example using `curl` command;

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8000/snippets/<pk>/

# example;

$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8000/snippets/99999/
```

Hope it can help..

---

### Update

If you want to handle for all error 404 urls with DRF, DRF also provide about it with [`APIException`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#apiexception), this answer may help you; https://stackoverflow.com/a/30628065/6396981

I'll give an example how do with it;

**1. `views.py`**

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import NotFound

def error404(request):
    raise NotFound(detail="Error 404, page not found", code=404)
```

**2. `urls.py`**

```
from django.conf.urls import (
  handler400, handler403, handler404, handler500)

from yourapp.views import error404

handler404 = error404
```

> Makesure your `DEBUG = False`

Comment: tried this with `DEBUG=FALSE` nothing I get a `500` status @SancaKembang

Comment: @SancaKembang me to ,tried this with DEBUG=FALSE nothing I get a 500,django=3.x

Answer (score 12):

```
from rest_framework import status    
from rest_framework.response import Response

# return 404 status code    
return Response({'status': 'details'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Answer (score 6):

An easier way is to use `get_object_or_404` method in django:
as described in [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404):

> get_object_or_404(klass, *args, **kwargs) 
>
> -* Calls get() on a given model manager, but it raises Http404 instead of the model’s DoesNotExist exception. 
>
> -* klass: A Model class, a Manager, or a QuerySet instance from which to get the object.

As an example, pay attention to

```
obj = get_object_or_404(Snippet, pk=pk)
return obj
```

in the following code:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from snippets.models import Snippet
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class SnippetDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a snippet instance.
    """
    def get_object(self, pk):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Snippet, pk=pk)
        return obj

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply, you can use the same structure of DRF, without losing I18N and keep the same DRF error message:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, status, exceptions
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response

try:
  codename = get_or_bad_request(self.request.query_params, 'myparam')
  return Response(self.get_serializer(MyModel.objects.get(myparam=codename), many=False).data)
except MyModel.DoesNotExist as ex:
  exc = exceptions.NotFound()
  data = {'detail': exc.detail}
  return Response(data, exc.status_code)
```

Comment: Where does `get_or_bad_request` come from? Does not seem to be in the rest docs.